# Unable to remove white space from data frame and hence was not able to find mean

Tags: r, regex, list, matrix, whitespace

I need to find the mean of this value where
class(newtemp)
is character .The data was original 10.6 °C like this. i removed °C but space is there due to which as.numeric is not working.

```
newtemp

 [1] "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-11.0 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 "

[12] "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-11.0 "

[23] "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-11.0 " "-10.6 " "-10.0 " "-10.0 " "-10.0 " "-10.0 " "-10.0 " "-9.4 " 

[34] "-8.9 "  "-8.3 "  "-7.2 "  "-7.2 "  "-5.6 "  "-5.0 "  "-3.9 "  "-3.9 "  "-3.9 "  "-3.3 "  "-3.3 " 

[45] "-3.9 "  "-6.1 "  "-8.3 "  "-7.8 "  "-8.9 "  "-10.0 " "-11.7 " "-12.8 "


#Tried this
library(stringr)
try=str_replace_all(newtemp, fixed(" "), "") but not able to remove
#Tried this also
trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
trim(x =newtemp)
# STill not removed

as.numeric(try)

 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

[36] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion 
#Sill no output.
```

The code i m using is :

```
    library(rvest)
linkurl="https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KVAY/2015/2/17/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Cherry+Hill&req_state=NJ&req_statename=New+Jersey&reqdb.zip=08002&reqdb.magic=1&reqdb.wmo=99999&MR=1"
weathertable=read_html(linkurl)%>%html_node("#obsTable")%>%html_table()
weathertable
newtemp=weathertable$Temp.

abc=(gsub("°C", "", newtemp))
abc
abc_new=(gsub("[[:space:]]", "", abc))
as.numeric(abc_new)
trimws(x=abc)
as.numeric(trimws(x=abc))
```

Update

```
        > newtemp
     [1] "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-11.0 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C"
    [10] "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C"
    [19] "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-11.0 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-11.0 °C" "-10.6 °C"
    [28] "-10.0 °C" "-10.0 °C" "-10.0 °C" "-10.0 °C" "-10.0 °C" "-9.4 °C"  "-8.9 °C"  "-8.3 °C"  "-7.2 °C" 
    [37] "-7.2 °C"  "-5.6 °C"  "-5.0 °C"  "-3.9 °C"  "-3.9 °C"  "-3.9 °C"  "-3.3 °C"  "-3.3 °C"  "-3.9 °C" 
    [46] "-6.1 °C"  "-8.3 °C"  "-7.8 °C"  "-8.9 °C"  "-10.0 °C" "-11.7 °C" "-12.8 °C"
    > abc=(gsub(" °C", "", newtemp))
    > abc
     [1] "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-11.0 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C"
    [10] "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C"
    [19] "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-11.0 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-10.6 °C" "-11.0 °C" "-10.6 °C"
    [28] "-10.0 °C" "-10.0 °C" "-10.0 °C" "-10.0 °C" "-10.0 °C" "-9.4 °C"  "-8.9 °C"  "-8.3 °C"  "-7.2 °C" 
    [37] "-7.2 °C"  "-5.6 °C"  "-5.0 °C"  "-3.9 °C"  "-3.9 °C"  "-3.9 °C"  "-3.3 °C"  "-3.3 °C"  "-3.9 °C" 
    [46] "-6.1 °C"  "-8.3 °C"  "-7.8 °C"  "-8.9 °C"  "-10.0 °C" "-11.7 °C" "-12.8 °C"
    > abc=(gsub("°C", "", newtemp))
> abc
 [1] "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-11.0 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 "
[12] "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-11.0 "
[23] "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-10.6 " "-11.0 " "-10.6 " "-10.0 " "-10.0 " "-10.0 " "-10.0 " "-10.0 " "-9.4 " 
[34] "-8.9 "  "-8.3 "  "-7.2 "  "-7.2 "  "-5.6 "  "-5.0 "  "-3.9 "  "-3.9 "  "-3.9 "  "-3.3 "  "-3.3 " 
[45] "-3.9 "  "-6.1 "  "-8.3 "  "-7.8 "  "-8.9 "  "-10.0 " "-11.7 " "-12.8 "
>
```

Comment: Can you please show the output of `lapply(newtemp[1:5], charToRaw)` to understand the character code of the "white space"?

Comment: Show how you removed centigrades.

Comment: @RYoda your command gives output as follows : [[1]]
[1] 2d 31 30 2e 36 c2 a0

[[2]]
[1] 2d 31 30 2e 36 c2 a0

[[3]]
[1] 2d 31 31 2e 30 c2 a0

[[4]]
[1] 2d 31 30 2e 36 c2 a0

[[5]]
[1] 2d 31 30 2e 36 c2 a0

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i removed centigrades by 
abc=(gsub("°C", "", newtemp))

Comment: You might use `gsub("(*UCP)\\s*°C", "", newtemp, perl=TRUE)`. Let me know if that works and if I should post it with explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it worked well. Please post it with explanation.

Comment: Using `gsub("\\s°C", "", newtemp)` works just as well

Comment: No need to, there is an accepted answer already.Guess you are on Windows.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nops i am on Ubuntu and it would b great if u explain it little it wont harm anyone.

Comment: @Jaap it is not doing any change.

Comment: Ok, though it will take some time: I'm on a mobile phone travelling by train and constantly losing Internet connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your strings contain a whitespace other than a regular ASCII space (decimal value 32). Thus, you need a regex that will match any Unicode whitespace. It is curious that a simple `gsub("[[:space:]]*°C", "", newtemp)` does not work in all R environments.

What usually works is a PCRE regex:

```
gsub("(*UCP)\\s*°C", "", newtemp, perl=TRUE)
```

Here, `(*UCP)` is a PCRE verb making the shorthand character classes Unicode-aware and `\s` can match any Unicode whitespaces. The `perl=TRUE` argument makes R use a PCRE regex engine rather than the default TRE regex engine.

Comment: Great solution!!! For other readers: c2 a0 = byte representation of non-breaking space in UTF-8 encoding (see http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use function `trimws`.

```
> x <- "-10.6 "
> trimws(x)
[1] "-10.6"
> as.numeric(trimws(x))
[1] -10.6
```

*UPDATE*

This appears to work for your case.

```
abc <- gsub("(^[-]\\d+\\.\\d+)(.*$)", "\\1", newtemp)
data.frame(new = abc, old = newtemp)
     new      old
1  -10.6 -10.6 °C
2  -10.6 -10.6 °C
3  -11.0 -11.0 °C
4  -10.6 -10.6 °C
5  -10.6 -10.6 °C
6  -10.6 -10.6 °C
7  -10.6 -10.6 °C
8  -10.6 -10.6 °C
9  -10.6 -10.6 °C
10 -10.6 -10.6 °C
11 -10.6 -10.6 °C
12 -10.6 -10.6 °C
13 -10.6 -10.6 °C
14 -10.6 -10.6 °C
...
```

Something is going on with character "conversion" that is over my head so I'm unable to explain what is going wrong. The way I'm tacking the problem is ignoring the `°C` part which appears to be offending, and just extracting the numeric part using [regular expression](https://regex101.com/). In a nut shell, I use special characters to find minus ([-] finds a minus or nothing), digits (\d+ finds all digits in a row), dots (\.) and end of the sentence ($), put everything in groups (using `()`) and then extract the first group, leaving everything else "behind".

Here's raw character

```
> charToRaw(newtemp[1])
 [1] 2d 31 30 2e 36 c2 a0 c2 b0 43
```

and if I copy/paste it into R

```
> charToRaw("-10.6 °C")
[1] 2d 31 30 2e 36 20 b0 43
```

Perhaps someone with more computer skills can chip in what's going on.

Comment: It is still not removed spaces are still there.. Please refer the above code

Comment: gsub expression worked fine. can you elaborte what it actually did and where i was going wrong

Comment: c2 a0 = byte representation of non-breaking space in UTF-8 encoding (see http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/). The space the OP shows us is **NOT** the normal 0x20 byte. This explains why it is so difficult to replace and convert to numeric.

Comment: @RYoda yepp, but I would be interested to know what happens in the rvest pipeline to render these strings this way.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the whole issue by using `readr::parse_number`:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KVAY/2015/2/17/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Cherry+Hill&req_state=NJ&req_statename=New+Jersey&reqdb.zip=08002&reqdb.magic=1&reqdb.wmo=99999&MR=1"

h <- url %>% read_html()

obs <- h %>% 
    html_node('#obsTable') %>% 
    html_table() 

obs_clean <- obs %>% 
    mutate(Temp. = parse_number(Temp.)) %>% 
    tbl_df()   # for printing

obs_clean
#> # A tibble: 52 x 13
#>    `Time (EST)` Temp. Windchill `Dew Point` Humidity Pressure Visibility
#>           <chr> <dbl>     <chr>       <chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr>
#>  1     12:33 AM  12.9         -      8.1 °F      81% 30.08 in     2.0 mi
#>  2     12:45 AM  12.9         -      8.1 °F      81% 30.05 in     1.2 mi
#>  3     12:51 AM  12.2         -      8.6 °F      85% 30.05 in     0.8 mi
#>  4     12:54 AM  12.9         -      9.0 °F      84% 30.06 in     0.8 mi
#>  5      1:02 AM  12.9         -      9.0 °F      84% 30.05 in     0.5 mi
#>  6      1:25 AM  12.9         -      9.0 °F      84% 30.02 in     1.0 mi
#>  7      1:37 AM  12.9    6.9 °F      9.0 °F      84% 30.03 in     0.8 mi
#>  8      1:54 AM  12.9    6.9 °F      9.0 °F      84% 30.02 in     0.8 mi
#>  9      2:18 AM  12.9    5.2 °F      9.0 °F      84% 30.01 in     1.0 mi
#> 10      2:40 AM  12.9    5.2 °F      9.0 °F      84% 29.99 in     1.0 mi
#> # ... with 42 more rows, and 6 more variables: `Wind Dir` <chr>, `Wind
#> #   Speed` <chr>, `Gust Speed` <chr>, Precip <chr>, Events <chr>,
#> #   Conditions <chr>
```

or with regex,

```r
obs %>% mutate(Temp. = as.numeric(gsub('[\\W°FC]', '', Temp.))) %>% tbl_df()
```

which returns the same thing.